# Can't upload image on redmine 5 using ckeditor

Tags: docker, ckeditor, redmine, redmine-plugins

I running a redmine 5.0.5.stable in docker based on the docker official image. After installed redminex-ck-editor I found pictures over 110k can't be uploaded.

```
Error Message:
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 20.2ms)
TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:61:in `sudo_mode'
```

Is there any place where this limit can be set? or something need to be  set in order to upload images using ckeditor

Thanks a lot.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This fix work for me

```
On plugin section, redmine_ckeditor\assets\javascripts\browser.js
line 318
from
handlerClass = 'UploadHandlerXhr';
to
handlerClass = 'UploadHandlerForm';
```

Regards